# How to do google sheet filtering?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, counting, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQ9j9EuHnvBPi_IYhheTbttwG-D5JHYcSGodSl3eSydEG1z5R7PFfKAOw6G-XrNEZQnxvDg_-5PmgDp/pubhtml

**I have a google sheet like the above link it looks like this**

```
Timestamp           Name

6/29/2020 23:32:42  aaaa

6/29/2020 23:32:50  aaaa

6/29/2020 23:32:54  aaaa

6/29/2020 23:33:00  bbbbb

6/29/2020 23:33:05  bbbbb

6/29/2020 23:33:10  bbbbb

6/29/2020 23:33:10  bbbbb
```

**But I need to get/create an output like this**

```
Name     NumberOfItem

aaaa         3

bbbbb        4
```

**How can I do this on google sheet**

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask] (there are a lot of ways to do that but the easier is to use a pivot table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(B2:B; "select B,count(B) where B is not null group by B label count(B)''")
```

[image]